# Sucess Ajax não funciona com Controller Codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Boa Tarde, sou iniciante em desenvolvimento.

Tenho um form cujo não quero que a pagina nao seja recarregada quando o usuario submita o form. pra isso estou usando Ajax, consegui realizar a inclusão no banco utilizando o codeigniter+ajax, porem a instrução sucess do ajax não está sendo invocada, gostaria de saber como faço para invoca-la, desde já agradeço`

Controller

```
public function agendar()
{
        $data['nome'] = $this->input->post('nome');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['celular'] = $this->input->post('celular');
        $data['dia'] = $this->input->post('dia');
        $data['hora'] = $this->input->post('hora');

        echo $this->db->insert('agenda',$data);

    }
```

Ajax

```
 $("#formulario").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
              $.ajax({
                       url: 'http://localhost/Odontologia/odonto/agendar',
                       type: 'POST',
                       data: {
                           nome: $('#nome').val(),
                           email: $('#email').val(),
                           celular: $('#txttelefone').val(),
                           dia: $('#dia').val(),
                           hora: $('#hora').val()
                       },

                       sucess: function() {                              
                             alert('teste');

                           }

                   });
               });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está digitado de forma  errada, o correto é:

```
success
```

você também pode usar o error, caso ocorra algum problema, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
    success: function(){
                alert("teste");
            },
    error: function(){
                alert("erro");  
            }
```